Ubuntu 24.04 with Xfce4, Remote Access to Wayland
I currently don't have access to a physical computer I can control, but I do have a VPS running Ubuntu 24.04. I want to run Waydroid to containerize an Android app, but can't figure out how to enable Wayland sessions instead of X11 while remoting in. I am using Xfce4+xrdp on a headless system because the VPS only has 4x2.4ghz cores and 6Gb RAM, and running Gnome (with all its pretty effects) really lags.
I used to use VNC, but couldn't figure out how to have the system spawn sessions for any user that remotes in (I share the server with another user, though I am the nominal admin). Is using Wayland via xrdp even possible? Should I be using something else besides xrdp?
Depending on the RDP client I use, I can get the login manager that allows me to set my session, but the choices are only: Xorg, Xvnc, vnc-any, and neutrinordp-any.
